# Simple Regression for calculating slope using apache maths in Java

Tags: java, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate the slope using simple regression.
Here is my two Arrays:

```
XLIST  [9.570915222167969 , 7.601962566375732 , 6.5179524421691895 , 5.71270227432251 , 5.095747947692871 , 4.610823631286621 , 4.221418380737305 , 3.902977705001831 , 3.6384739875793457 , 3.4157819747924805]
YList [10.0 , 11.0 , 12.0 , 13.0 , 14.0 , 15.0 , 16.0 , 17.0 , 18.0 , 19.0]
```

However, the slope is `7.9192681940221545` using below:

```
double[][] pqr={ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(xList.toArray(new Double[0])),ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(yList.toArray(new Double[0]))};
simpleRegression.addData(pqr);
System.out.println(" The slope" + simpleRegression.getSlope());
```

However, I am able to see a discrepancy in the excel slope, i.e., -0.6132.

I am not sure where am I doing the mistake.

Any info in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the data wrong to the `addData(double[][])` method.

The `addData` method assumes that you're passing in an array of x-y pairs. Instead your passing in x values and y values in two separate arrays. You can either create an array of the right shape, or pass the data in with the other methods available. For example

```
for (int i=0; i<xList.size(); i++)
    simpleRegression.addData(xList.get(i), yList.get(i));
```